# Programmatically adding folders & layers to QgsComposerLegend

Tags: qgis, python, legend

I've been building up `QgsLayerTree` object with a directory structure that reflects the desired legend.

Specifically, I'd like the Group(s) to be titles and their contained layers to legend items. However, only blank spaces appear where the Group's title would be. 
You can see here:

[image: example]

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
    ### LEGEND
    composerLegend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
    composerLegend.setColumnCount(3)
    composerLegend.setEqualColumnWidth(True)
    composerLegend.setBackgroundEnabled(True)
    composerLegend.setBackgroundColor(QColor('white'))
    composerLegend.setFrameEnabled(True)
    composerLegend.setFrameOutlineColor(QColor('red'))
    composerLegend.setFrameOutlineWidth(1)
    composerLegend.setTitle('Land Uses')
    composerLegend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Title, QFont("Ubuntu", 60))
    composerLegend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Group, QFont("Ubuntu", 50))
    composerLegend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Subgroup, QFont("Ubuntu", 30))
    composerLegend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.SymbolLabel, QFont("Ubuntu", 15))
    composerLegend.setSymbolHeight(5)
    composerLegend.setSymbolWidth(10)
    output_group = self.findGroup('Land Uses')
    composerLegend.modelV2().setRootGroup(output_group)
    #composerLegend.synchronizeWithModel()
    composerLegend.adjustBoxSize() # this is the last operation before adding
    c.addItem(composerLegend)
    self.setLegendPosition(composerLegend, 10, 10)
```